# How to render the shiny's output via plumber/REST API to other programmers?

Tags: r, rest, api, shiny, plumber

Hey Shiny and Plumber experts,

Relevant links :
https://abndistro.com/post/2019/07/06/deploying-a-plumber-api-on-aws-ec2-instance/

https://abndistro.com/post/2019/07/06/deploying-a-shiny-app-with-shiny-server-on-an-aws-ec2-instance/

Basically, we are trying to pass the output of shiny via Plumber to other programmers to integrate in an webpage.

From the documentation, running on local machine,
following works individually:

## Plumber reprex

```
#* Plot a histogram
#* @png
#* @get /plot
function(){
  random_num <- rnorm(10) * 5
  hist(random_num)
}
saving the file as plumber.R
# Running the below in console 
r <- plumb("plumber.R")  # Where 'plumber.R' is the location of the file shown above
r$run(port=8000)

# Now, loading the browser: http://127.0.0.1:8000/__swagger__/ 
[![plumber output][1]][1]
```

## Similarly shiny reprex :

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI for application that plots random distributions 
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", 
                  "Number of observations:", 
                  min = 1, 
                  max = 1000, 
                  value = 500)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))

# Define server logic required to generate and plot a random distribution
server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Expression that generates a plot of the distribution. The expression
  # is wrapped in a call to renderPlot to indicate that:
  #
  #  1) It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically 
  #     re-executed when inputs change
  #  2) Its output type is a plot 

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate an rnorm distribution and plot it
    dist <- rnorm(input$obs)
    hist(dist)
  })

})

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## How can we render shiny's output i.e histogram into plumber's swagger ?

i.e. How to display the user

## Tried: Embedding the plumber function within Shiny's renderFunction

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI for application that plots random distributions 
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", 
                  "Number of observations:", 
                  min = 1, 
                  max = 1000, 
                  value = 500)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))

# Define server logic required to generate and plot a random distribution
server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Expression that generates a plot of the distribution. The expression
  # is wrapped in a call to renderPlot to indicate that:
  #
  #  1) It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically 
  #     re-executed when inputs change
  #  2) Its output type is a plot 


  #### Embedding inside the shiny
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    #* Plot a histogram
    #* @png
    #* @get /plot
    function(){
    # generate an rnorm distribution and plot it
    dist <- rnorm(input$obs)
    hist(dist)
    }
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have a look at this `parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)` https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/url-inputs

Comment: Thanks @PorkChop for reference. In the link, he explains to update the URL but not the inputs from Shiny. Also, he doesnt use  plumber. Would it be possible to share more relevant hints/example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the plotting function cleanly outside the ui/server definitions. The code below works as shiny app and also is parsed correctly by plumber:

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI for application that plots random distributions 

ui = fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", 
                  "Number of observations:", 
                  min = 1, 
                  max = 1000, 
                  value = 500)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

#* Plot a histogram
#* @param n Number or observations
#* @get /plothist
#* @serializer png
plothist <- function(n){
  # generate an rnorm distribution and plot it
  dist <- rnorm(as.integer(n))
  hist(dist, breaks=100)
}

server = function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    plothist(input$obs)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```